# AJAX filter plugin in Wordpress

Tags: ajax, wordpress, filter

I have a post type lets say schools, in the website, I want to create a advanced filters, like I can filter via region and province, school type (public or private). Do you know any good plugins for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this below plugins

1. Search & Filter (https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-filter/)
2. facetwp Plugin (https://facetwp.com/)
3. Relevanssi (https://wordpress.org/plugins/relevanssi/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the Live Search and Custom Fields plugin - it comes in 2 versions:

- Free: https://wordpress.org/plugins/live-search-custom-fields-lite/
- Pro:
  https://codecanyon.net/item/live-search-and-custom-fields/18598007